# How Delete session from visitor browser

Tags: php

I have problem with session, I try `unset($_SESSION)` and `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` session destroyed but still show in browser (cookie extension)

I want remove it finality like `session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 10])` but I not want set a time, I want only remove it in a location on my php code, any idea?

My code here:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['style'] = $style;
echo "Your style is : " . $style;
unset($_SESSION['style']);
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session cookie stored in the browser simply contains a reference to the session ID on the server and does not contain any actual session data. All of that is stored solely on the server and it would actually be a huge security issue if it were stored client-side. If you delete the session on the server, this deletes all data stored on the server to do with that session and any attempt to re-authenticate using the old session ID will fail. If the browser sends an old session cookie back to the server after the session has been destroyed, it will simply be ignored by the server. Therefore there is no need to delete the session cookie from the user's browser since this will be done automatically by the browser when the window is closed. The recommended way to kill a session is simply to do:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

However, with that said, if you want to manually force the cookie to be deleted for whatever reason:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['style'] = $style;
echo "Your style is : " . $style;
unset($_SESSION['style']);

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', -1,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
```

Comment: maybe this will work too : `session_destroy();`

`session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 0]);` please tell me if this is good ?

Comment: @MisterBrooks Even though something might "work" doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it like that. To me, when I see `session_start()` in my mind I'm thinking it's starting a session, not that it's actually deleting the session cookie since the cookie's lifetime is set to `0`, even though that's what it's doing. Seeing this code would make me do a double-take, and you don't want future coders (or yourself in 3 years) to have to think too much about your code. Always code for readability whenever possible. But if you feel this is not confusing to you, go ahead and use it.

Comment: i'm using your code and it's work like charm, thank you bro